# Why Isn't Huckles rule applicable to more than 3 fused rings

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, aromaticity

[image: Compound A]

In the following compound **(Pyrene)** why isn't **Huckle's (4n+2) rule** applicable? I do know it is applicable to only mono-cyclic ring systems but what changes when there are more than 3 fused rings?

Edit:

A similar question has been posted previously but that doesn't mention as to why only the peripheral bonds are to be considered.

Comment: @thewitness please do see the edit

Comment: That is because the double bond in the centre doesn't take part in resonance. It is quite similar to the lone pair in pyridine and the "second" lone pair in furan where we don't consider them as a part of π electrons while applying Haeckel's Rule. We require a complete conjunction to classify a compound into aromatic or non aromatic. In case there is no complete conjugation, it is non aromatic.

Comment: So in any of such compounds the double bonds not along the periphery do not involve in resonance?

Comment: It depends on whether or not it can participate in resonance.

Comment: So the peripheral rule isn't applicable everywhere?

Comment: @thewitness " double bond in the centre doesn't take part in resonance" -it's impossible, also its taking part in resonance isn't a problem at all.

Comment: Huckle's rule is  applicable to specific rings not whole compounds. If compound has at least 1 aromatic ring, then it's aromatic.